# Adjust something to something

Tags: word-usage

I know I can say "adjust something to something". Can I use the verb adjust in the way below?

> I adjusted the piston to rotating at intervals of five minutes.

Comment: No. **Adjusted** doesn't work with **rotating**. Your sentence should read: **I adjusted the piston to rotate at intervals of five minutes.**  (PS. We don't usually do students' homework. Such questions generally get put ON HOLD unless they raise a specific point of grammar.)

Comment: (1) *I adjusted the piston, **rotating it** at intervals of five minutes.* (2) *I adjusted the piston to **rotate** at intervals of five minutes.* (3) *I adjusted the piston to **a rotation interval** of five minutes.* (Each version means something slightly different.)